# Perform Insert operation when two tables are related by foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have creates two tables in sql server 2008  [image: db diagram]

as shown in diagram

I have added some data in product table

```
insert into tblproduct values ("I PHONE");
insert into tblproduct values ("SAMSUNG");
insert into tblproduct values ("SONY");
...etc
```

Now my Question is how will I write sql statement for inserting data in tblOrder
so that Pid will be automatically filled in tblOrder.

Comment: Are you looking to `UPDATE` existing records in tblOrder? or just insert records into the table?

Comment: no i m looking for insertion operation

Comment: We are missing something, are you only using SQL ? Is it an application  ?

Comment: yes i am using sql server 2008 r2 just for learning sql statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to answer to your question sql data are manipulated by sql language. But sql server is just a way to saved structured data.

So, when you are building an application, and you are listing products available to order, you know the ids of thoses products. And then you can do something like :

```
INSERT INTO tblOrder(OName, Pid)
VALUES ('name_choosen', [product_id_selected])
```

In your case, for sql training, you do :

```
INSERT INTO tblOrder(OName, Pid)
SELECT 'name_of_order', Pid
FROM tblProduct
WHERE PName='IPhone'
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO tblOrder(OName, Pid)
SELECT 'name_of_order'
      , (SELECT Pid from tblProduct WHERE PName='IPhone')
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO tblOrder(OName, Pid)
VALUES ('name_of_order'
      , (SELECT Pid from tblProduct WHERE PName='IPhone'))
```

Comment: what's this [product_id_selected]. can you please explain

Comment: Ok, when are running code, that will perform sql insert, you will see something like (in PHP) $productID = 2; then $sql="INSERT INTO tblOrder(OName, Pid) VALUES ('order_name', $productID)"; then mysqli_query($con, $sql) this will execute sql query

Comment: I'm just trying to say, in real life, you will never do the specific thing you want just in SQL, you will do it from an application. It's just a specific case. But I understand that you are training yourself in SQL ;)

Comment: you mean that $productID will be dynamically retrieved

Comment: Not at all, before in application you retrieved all informations from tblProduct with `SELECT * FROM tblProduct`, you know which id match this product name. Then you choose your product (like in drop down list in web form page) and you inject the related `ID` in the `INSERT INTO tblOrder`

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?  Great answer, you really took the time.

Comment: @paqogomez I guess someone was angry at me and voted down just 10sec after my post. But it's ok ;) Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Nida, as you gave him the answer, i'll assume it wasnt you that downvoted him, but it is customary to upvote your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620086/CASCADE-in-SQL-Server-with-example

Happy coding.

Try using the INSERT ON CASCADE.

Comment: How does an article on `ON DELETE CASCADE` help with inserting records?  Link only answers are frowned upon, you should add the salient points of the article to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblOrder(OName, Pid)
SELECT 'nameOfOrder',Pid
FROM tblProduct
WHERE PName='IPhone'.
```

You need to extract PID from products table rather than inserting PID directly in Orders table.
This will ensure that all the pid's in order table are present in product tables.

Also you can't remember Pid's of every product but recognize product by there name ( Iphone,Samsung etc ) which is more convinient.